# intersystem cache C# query with datetime

Tags: intersystems-cache

When I use cache sql query in C# I'm getting an error:

```
SQLtext1 = "SELECT top 10 * FROM dbo.DAPPLICATIONSTAT where TIMESTAMP = '2015-02-01 00:00:00'"
```

I would like to use a where clause with a datetime filter.

I am using InterSystems.Data.CacheClient.dll to execute the query.

Error Messge :

```
[SQLCODE: <-4>:<A term expected, beginning with one of the following: identifier, constant, aggregate, %ALPHAUP, %EXACT, %MVR, %SQLSTRING, %SQLUPPER, %STRING, %UPPER, $$, :, +, -, (, NOT, EXISTS, or FOR>] 
[Cache Error: <<SYNTAX>errdone+2^%qaqqt>] [Details: <Prepare>] 
[%msg: < SQL ERROR #4: A term expected, beginning with either of: (, NOT, EXISTS, or FOR^SELECT top :%qpar(1) * FROM dbo . DAPPLICATIONSTAT where TIMESTAMP>
```

Comment: Which error, do you getting, and which version of Caché ?  You could, try to test your SQL requests in SystemManager Portal, in ODBC Mode. Or any other ODBC clients.

Comment: Hi, I am using InterSystems.Data.CacheClient.dll to execute the query from C#                                                                                      SQLtext1 = "SELECT top 10 * FROM dbo.DAPPLICATIONSTAT where TIMESTAMP = '2015-02-01 00:00:00'";
 CacheCommand Command1 = new CacheCommand(SQLtext1, CacheConnect); CacheDataReader Reader1 = Command1.ExecuteReader();

Comment: Error Messge : [SQLCODE: <-4>:<A term expected, beginning with one of the following: identifier, constant, aggregate, %ALPHAUP, %EXACT, %MVR, %SQLSTRING, %SQLUPPER, %STRING, %UPPER, $$, :, +, -, (, NOT, EXISTS, or FOR>]
[Cache Error: <<SYNTAX>errdone+2^%qaqqt>]
[Details: <Prepare>]
[%msg: < SQL ERROR #4: A term expected, beginning with either of:  (, NOT, EXISTS, or FOR^SELECT top :%qpar(1) * FROM dbo . DAPPLICATIONSTAT where TIMESTAMP>]

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have reserved word TIMESTAMP and so, you have that error
Try this SQL query, where filedname TIMESTAMP in dobled quotas

```
SELECT top 10 * FROM dbo.DAPPLICATIONSTAT where "TIMESTAMP" = '2015-02-01 00:00:00'
```